# matplotlib + latex + custom ttf font

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, latex

I have to make a figure in python. I need it to use the font Palatino. I downloaded the font [here](https://github.com/potyt/fonts/tree/master/macfonts/Palatino). I placed it under *\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf (which turned out to be useless since I had to provide full path to make it work).

Using the following lines allows me to use the font:

```
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname='C:/Users/MyPC/pyApp/venv/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Palatino-Roman.ttf')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = prop.get_name()
```

Yay.
Now when I want to use Latex in matplotlib,

```
rc('text',usetex=True)
```

the font is now not the one I want. I tried to follow [the official page about that](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/usetex.html) and instead use:

```
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

but I cannot see any difference. I tried all possibilities and it looks like the same font. 
What am I doing wrong? Perhaps its the latex side that's lacking the required font package...

Answer (score 2):

You can load any latex packages when using `rc('text',usetex=True)`

You can add this in your code:

```
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{palatino, mathpazo}']
```

Comment: I tried that and also helvetica and another font Bookman but I don't see any difference... Do you have another example with a clearly recognizable font? For my previous test I used Zapfino. Also, how do you edit the math font?

Comment: Maybe try `fpath = os.path.join(rcParams["datapath"], "'C:/Users/MyPC/pyApp/venv/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/Palatino-Roman.ttf'")` and then `prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=fpath)` and finally `fontproperties=prop` in your `set_xlabel`for example

Comment: But how to add any TTF font when using `usetex : True?`